# Read MS Access .MDB database in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ms-access

I am exploring porting [ATCS Monitor](http://www.atcsmon.com/) from Windows to the iPad and Mac OS X. [ATCS Monitor](http://www.atcsmon.com/) uses Microsoft JET 4.0 to read data from Access MDB files. Is there an Objective-C library that can read MDB files, or do I need to roll my own (most likely based on [MDB Tools](https://github.com/brianb/mdbtools))?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412987/use-mdb-file-instead-of-sqlite-in-ios-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Open Source Objective-C library for reading MDB files.

Here are all the ways I am aware of for reading MDB files on the Mac / iPhone:

1) [MDB Tools](http://github.com/brianb/mdbtools/): Version 0.7 is quite usable. Has a quite usable, allthough poorly documented C API. Supports reading tables. Is licensed under LGPL, so it might not be legal to use it on iOS, but shouldn't be a problem on Mac.

2) [Actual ODBC drivers for Access](http://www.actualtech.com/product_access.php) (proprietary): Only for the Mac. Maybe you can find some licensing agreement with the company making them.

3) [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net), originally a port of MDB Tools to Java, but they added write support. Probably only useful on the Mac.

4) [HXTT Access Pure Java JDBC](http://www.hxtt.com/access.html): A proprietary Java library for reading and writing Access databases. It's interesting because a [company name Impathic](http://www.impathic.com/) uses it in their Mac (and I believe iPhone) apps. They are completely crazy and they include a full Java runtime in their app package so they can distribute a Java app on the App Store, but it seems to work (albeit with a few bugs).

5) My own proprietary library. I wrote an Objective-C library (from scratch) for reading Access databases and I use it in my [Mac and iPhone apps](http://eggerapps.at). If you are interested in licensing it, contact me.

Comment: jackcess has extensive write support.

Comment: @jtahlborn I wasn't sure about Jackcess functionality, because I have never worked with it myself. I changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why does the data need to be an Access .mdb file for the iPad/OS X versions?

I don't know how the internals of the ATCS system work, but I would assume that the data is available via some type of web service. If the .mdb file is only used for storing data on the local machine, then your Objective-C implementation could use *any* local data storage system to do the same thing.

I just can't imagine a scenario in which the .mdb file was exposed in any manner external to the application. Does the program download an .mdb file and then read the data? If that's the case, then it would be easy enough to write your own web service that converts the data on the server to another format that could be better consumed by your Objective-C code.

**Edit:** So users are sharing .mdb files with each other. I still think your best bet would be a web service that converts the .mdb file into a format that's more easily consumed via iOS/Mac. In order for the Objective-C versions of the app to import an .mdb file, they'd need to be connected to the Internet at least for as long as it took for the web service to convert the data.

**Edit 2:** Maybe you've found a need that you should fill. If there is no central repository for sharing this data, then you could create such a repo and encourage users in the Yahoo groups to use it. Make it super easy for someone to upload and import their data from MDB files. Create a web interface in addition to the desktop interface. Aggregate the data from all the individual uploads. There are lots of possibilities!

I understand meeting users where they are, but it also sounds to me like there's a great opportunity to enable this particular user community to move into the 21st century.

Comment: The data in the MDB files is not under any centralized control, and is user generated on machines not necessarily connected to the internet while ATCS is running. I want to take data that was generated on Windows systems and shared and be able to import it into Mac OS X or iOS without requiring that the user have access to a Windows system to do so.

Comment: OK. How are the files shared if not via the Internet?

Comment: Yahoo user groups and email mostly.

Comment: How are Yahoo groups and email not the Internet?

Comment: It's not that the Internet is not used to share files, its that a well-defined API for data is not available, even on the Internet. Email, incidentally, predates the Internet.

Comment: OK, I think I understand, but your first comment was that the machines weren't connected to the Internet. They are connected to the net, but just not sharing data via a centralized server or site. My point was that you could still use a web service to handle the translation from MDB do another data format because users are at least occasionally connected to the net.

Answer (score 0):

I would import those MDB files to a MySQL DB (since OSX cannot really read those anyway), and have your OSX / Ipad client directly access that DB layer (or a web service providing access to those)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'd be asking users to do this, since the MDB files are often user generated and shared on related forums, since ATCS is only very weakly linked to the internet.