# Use .mdb file instead of SQLite in iOS app ?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite, ms-access

How can I use the `.mdb file` instead of `SQLite`, I am working on a project that will load and update data from `.mdb file`. I search about it but can't found anything can you poeple guide me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read MS Access .MDB database in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753412/read-ms-access-mdb-database-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 4):

[MDB Tools is an opensource project](https://github.com/brianb/mdbtools) that aims to bring support of the prorpietary MDB file format of Microsoft Access to POSIX systems. Since it's written in pure C, it should be fairly easy to integrate this project in your iOS app. (You should specifically be looking at its `libmdb` part.)

Comment: Keep in mind that mdbtools is licensed under LGPL, which means it may not be legal to include it in an iPhone app (that's why I wrote my own library for reading mdb files)

Answer (score -3):

.mdb is not supported with iOS API. You should convert your .mdb file into sqlite file to access through iOS API.

Comment: This answer suggests that "this is impossible", which is rarely true in the field of programming.

Comment: and he is right , it is impossible since also the LGPL license which is make the libmdb forbidden for ios apps